# Byte and bitwise operators

Tags: compiler-errors, kotlin, byte, bitwise-operators

I tested the code:

```
val a : Int = 0x01
val b : Int = 0x03
println(a and b)
```

and got:

```
1
```

But if I declare as `Byte`s:

```
val a : Byte = 0x01
val b : Byte = 0x03
println(a and b)
```

got error:

```
error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
@SinceKotlin @InlineOnly public inline infix fun BigInteger.and(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin
println(a and b)
          ^
```

I found the reference: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.experimental/and.html saying:

> Platform and version requirements: Kotlin 1.1

I checked my version:

```
C:\>kotlinc.bat -version
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.2.30 (JRE 1.8.0_181-b13)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the import statement:

```
import kotlin.experimental.and
```

Without the import the compiler tries to use the `and` found in `BigIntegers.kt`.

Comment: Why Intellj IDEA doesn't suggest this ?:)